# Problem displaying information from an API in my Text in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using information from an API, the process goes well until the moment of capture (I use a print that shows me that if I obtained the data), the problem is that when displaying it, I do not know if **Null safety** has to do with something, but I can't show the data in my **Text**, maybe something I'm doing wrong and I haven't noticed, I would appreciate if you could help me, here is the code:

GET: // *request works fine I can see the information in the **print***

```
Future<Welcome2> obtener2() async {
    var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
    var response = await http.get(
      Uri.parse(url),
    );
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {

      print(response.body.toString());
     
      return Welcome2.fromJson(json.decode(response.body));
      
    } else {
      throw Exception('Fallo al cargar la lista');
    }
  }
```

My class modal:

```
class Welcome2 {
  final int? userId;
  final int? id;
  final String? title;
  final bool? completed;

  Welcome2({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.completed});

  factory Welcome2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome2(
        userId: json["userId"] ?? json["userId"].toString(),
        id: json["id"] ?? json["id"].toString(),
        title: json["title"] ?? json["title"].toString(),
        completed: json["completed"] ?? json["completed"].toString(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson() => {
        "userId": userId,
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "completed": completed,
      };

  List<Welcome2> welcome2FromJson(String str) =>
      List<Welcome2>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Welcome2.fromJson(x)));

  String welcome2ToJson(List<Welcome2> data) =>
      json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
}
```

My Widget where I want to show the information obtained but it does not show it to me (it jumps to: return Text ('There is no data');)

```
class _Vista2State extends State<Vista2> {
  MIsDatos mIsDatos = MIsDatos();
  late Future<Welcome2> listado;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listado = listarP();
  }

  Future<Welcome2> listarP() async {
    return this.mIsDatos.obtener2();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('LISTADO'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.android)),
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<Welcome2>(
          future: listado,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
              
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(snapshot.data!.id.toString()),
                    Text(snapshot.data!.userId.toString()),
                    Text(snapshot.data!.title.toString()),
                  ],
                );

              } else {
                return Text('No ha datos'); // ME MUESTRA ESTE MENSAJE Y NO LO QUE TENGO EN MI Text
              }
            } else {
              return Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                ),
              );
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from your sample code, it seem your are return the wrong structure of data. it should be a `List<Welcome2>` since the returned json data is an array of objects

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 1,
    "title": "delectus aut autem",
    "completed": false
  },
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "id": 2,
    "title": "quis ut nam facilis et officia qui",
    "completed": false
  },
]
```

your `obtener2()` function should be:

```
Future<List<Welcome2>> obtener2() async {
  var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {

    print(response.body.toString());

    return Welcome2().welcome2FromJson(response.body);

  } else {
    throw Exception('Fallo al cargar la lista');
  }
}
```

I have made a number of changes to your sample code. find the full code below:

```
Future<List<Welcome2>> obtener2() async {
  var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/";
  var response = await http.get(
    Uri.parse(url),
  );
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return Welcome2().welcome2FromJson(response.body);
  } else {
    throw Exception('Fallo al cargar la lista');
  }
}

class Welcome2 {
  final int? userId;
  final int? id;
  final String? title;
  final bool? completed;

  Welcome2({this.userId, this.id, this.title, this.completed});

  factory Welcome2.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Welcome2(
        userId: json["userId"] ?? json["userId"].toString(),
        id: json["id"] ?? json["id"].toString(),
        title: json["title"] ?? json["title"].toString(),
        completed: json["completed"] ?? json["completed"].toString(),
      );

  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson() => {
        "userId": userId,
        "id": id,
        "title": title,
        "completed": completed,
      };

  List<Welcome2> welcome2FromJson(String str) =>
      List<Welcome2>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Welcome2.fromJson(x)));

  String welcome2ToJson(List<Welcome2> data) =>
      json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));
}

class Vista2 extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Vista2State createState() => _Vista2State();
}

class _Vista2State extends State<Vista2> {
  // MIsDatos mIsDatos = MIsDatos();
  late Future<List<Welcome2>> listado;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listado = listarP();
  }

  Future<List<Welcome2>> listarP() async {
    return obtener2();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('LISTADO'),
          actions: [
            IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.android)),
          ],
        ),
        body: FutureBuilder<List<Welcome2>>(
          future: listado,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return CircularProgressIndicator.adaptive();
            }

            switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
              case ConnectionState.none:
                return Text('No data');
              case ConnectionState.waiting:
                return Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.red,
                  ),
                );
              default:
                if (snapshot.data == null) {
                  return Text('No ha datos');
                }

                return ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(snapshot.data![index].id.toString()),
                      Text(snapshot.data![index].userId.toString()),
                      Text(snapshot.data![index].title.toString()),
                    ],
                  );
                });
            }
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

Comment: OH great if it works, thanks. A question friend, and if I wanted to do a tour within the Listview with "map ()", how would it be?

Comment: For example I have tried to do it like this: return ListView (
                  children: snapshot.data! .welcome.map ((e) {
                    return Text (e.title!);
                  }). toList (),
                ); but it doesn't show me the result         
But if you show me with Listview.builder

Comment: That approach is possible but Not efficient. Using Listview.builder optimizes the displaying of the data